# Owl Carousel 2 inside bootstrap accordion working only on window resize?

Tags: jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, window-resize, bootstrap-accordion

I am using Owl Carousel 2.
I want to load Owl Carousel inside the Bootstrap Accordion panel.
My code goes like this...

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="panel-group users_block_accordion" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#usersPanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          View Users in the Panel
        </h4>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="usersPanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
          <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/500x500" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(function() {    
  var $carousel = $(".users_block_accordion .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    navigation: true,
    navigationText: [
      "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
      "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
    ],
    items: 3
  });
});
```

I am also sharing the screenshot preview of whats happening.

Screenshot 1 (On page load - The Carousel looks like this)

[image]

Screenshot 2 (After resizing the screen - The Carousel looks like this)

[image]

Please help me out to make this load as soon as the page loads.. which lokks like Screenshot 2!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should initiate owl carousel on accordion shown.
Bootstrap accordion fires "shown.bs.collapse". [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion)

```
    $('#accordion').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
        var $carousel = $(".expert_block_accordion .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
            navigation: true,
            navigationText: [
                "<i class='icon-chevron-left icon-white'><</i>",
                "<i class='icon-chevron-right icon-white'>></i>"
            ],
            items: 3
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This May help (I Didn't chked)

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    heightStyle: "content",
    collapsible: true,
    active: 0,
    beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
         window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
}
});
```

OR

```
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").on('shown', function () {
    var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
    evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
});
```

Comment: This is regarding jQuery accordion not bootstrap accordion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue on owl-carousel. This script may help you, this is possible to resize the screen with particular div.

```
$(".accordion-toggle").on('click', function () {
    var width = $(".item").width();
    var owidth = width+"px";

    $(".wir").animate({"width":owidth}, 1);
});
```

Comment: Please have a look at how to format your answers on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Please also look again here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and make sure your answer really answers the question.