# carousel with two items displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel

I want to create carousel with two items displayed.
Check this example: https://codepen.io/samugleztrejo/pen/VjBJkg

I don't want it to be multiple blocks and each block with two items

```
<div>
  <item>
  <item>
</div>
<div>
  <item>
  <item>
</div>
```

I want to list all items in one block.

```
<div>
  <item></items>
  <item></items>
  <item></items>
  <item></items>
</div>
```

and display just two just like in the [example mentioned above](https://codepen.io/samugleztrejo/pen/VjBJkg)

Comment: two items displayed means?

Comment: yes, i want to display two iitems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

Make Use of Owl carousel 2, wrap `.itemC` divs in a `.item` div

HTML

```
<div id="owl-example1" class="owl-carousel">
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
         <div class="item">
           <div class="itemC">Your Content</div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#owl-example1").owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    items:2,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000,
  });   
    });
```

Style Accordingly and change the autoplay duration as needed

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/VzmWEv?editors=0010)

Comment: thank you,, that's it 
i found what i want in that link

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://codepen.io/Shiladitya/pen/PKbjMK

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-example1").owlCarousel({
    items:2,
    autoWidth:true,
    autoplay:false
  });
});
```

```css
.itemC{
    background:#ccc;
    height: 100px;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
  }

#owl-example1{
  .itemC{
    background:tomato;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div id="owl-example1" class="owl-carousel">
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
  <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but i want to display just two items

Comment: You need **1 carousel with two items** or **2 carousels with 2 items**

Comment: one carousel contain multiple items, and display only two 'items'

Comment: @lahmer.bechir Ya, it's possible just add autoplay:true; to carousel property. **Reference :** https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#owl-example1").owlCarousel();
  $("#owl-example2").owlCarousel();
  $("#owl-example3").owlCarousel();


});
/*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077159/owl-carousel-2-inside-bootstrap-accordion-working-only-on-window-resize*/
```

```css
.itemC {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 100px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

#owl-example1 {
  .itemC {
    background: tomato;
  }
}

#owl-example3 {
  .itemC {
    background: tan;
  }
}

#owl-example2 {
  .itemC {
    background: #ff8800;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="owl-example1" class="owl-carousel">
          <div>
            <div class="itemC"> Your Content </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="itemC"> Your Content </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: it ll contain multiple items (MORE THAN TWO ITEMS). i just want to display two

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  $("#owl-example1").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
     items:2,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:2,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        }
    }
});
  $("#owl-example2").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:2,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        }
    }
});
  $("#owl-example3").owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:2,
            nav:true
        },
        1000:{
            items:2,
            nav:true,
            loop:true
        }
    }
});
  
 
});
/*
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077159/owl-carousel-2-inside-bootstrap-accordion-working-only-on-window-resize*/
```

```css
  .itemC{
    background:#ccc;
    height: 100px;
    width:90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
  }

#owl-example1 .itemC{
    background:tomato;
}
#owl-example3 .itemC{
    background:tan;
}
#owl-example2 .itemC{
    background:#ff8800;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.owlcarousel/1.31/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
<div id="owl-example1" class="owl-carousel">
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>

</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
<div id="owl-example2" class="owl-carousel">
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>

</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
<div id="owl-example3" class="owl-carousel">
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>
    <div><div class="itemC"> Your Content </div></div>

</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```